# OpenJDK 8 with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I have installed OpenJDK 8 and want to create a JavaFX app. Since JavaFX is not included in OpenJDK 8, I tried to install OpenJFX via maven:
downloaded `org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11` and `org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11`. It seems fine, the libs are resolved.
But when I execute the program, I get the following error message:

```
    class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

So I think I have the wrong version of the libs, since Java 8 is class file version 52. Is there a OpenJFX lib available for Java 8. Or did I miss something else?

Comment: AFAIK Java SDK 8 is packed with javafx. If your using java SDK 11 and onward then your have to download javafx SDK separately

Comment: @UmerFarooq JavaFX is included with Oracle JDK 8, but not with OpenJDK8.

Comment: `org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11` is, as the name suggests, for Java 11.

Comment: Azul Systems has back-ported OpenJFX to Java 8. They even released a JDK that includes the OpenJFX libraries, known as *ZuluFX*. These products come free-of-cost or commercially-supported, your choice. See their [FAQ page](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/zulufx-faq/). I believe the same is true for *LibericaFX* from BellSoft.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of Java 8?

Comment: The problem is with javafx dependency. The available openjfx dependency is compiled with Java 10  (hence the version 54.0 instead of 52.0). I am also facing the same issue while trying to include openjfx with OpenJDK but have not found any workaround till now. If you have a solution, please let me know